# Button with IonicHistory.goBack()

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, back

I have a simple App built with Ionic/Cordova. In each page I want to create a simple "Go Back" block button - the user can press it to go to the previous page in the App.

I'm thinking of doing this using $ionicHistory. However, the method *$ionicHistory.goBack()* is not working.

I am currently using the usual *window.history.back()* instead, which works, but I don't understand why the ionic method is not working like it should.

Here is the view of the code:

```
<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="goBackHandler()">
   Go Back
</button>
```

And here is the Controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicHistory) 
{
    $scope.goBackHandler = function()
    {
        $ionicHistory.goBack();                      //This doesn't work
        //window.history.back();                          //This works
        //alert('code to go back called. Did it work?');  //For testing
    }
});
```

This should be pretty straight-forward. What could I be missing?

Edit: Plunker here - http://plnkr.co/yJqdfs

Comment: can you make a plunker.`$ionicHistory.goBack(); ` should work.

Comment: Here it is - http://plnkr.co/yJqdfs

Comment: try to wrap that with try-catch and give info about error.

Answer (score 2):

`$ionicHistory.goBack()` works only when you have routing and when you navigate to another screen using `$state.go('testPage')`.

In the plunker you've

`<a href="test.html">Go to Test Page</a>`

Which is a general browser redirection, which **IonicHistory** can't help you.

Ionic History will work based on the states stack it has.

Because when you redirect using `href="test.html"`, there will be NO state pushed to Ionic History, so `$ionicHistory.goBack()` couldn't find any back state.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this one. This works for me.

```
window.history.back();
```